# Explanation of inrementing pointer to integer. Pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
int * ptr = (int *) 0x108; // 264 in bin
printf("%d\n", ptr);
```

I don't really understand whats going on- when I do operation like `++` its adds 4 to the value (probably because the sizeof(int) is 4) but can someone explain to me here whats going on? I obtain error accessing such pointer. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a memory address, but no allocated to you. If you run this on valgrind:

```
int * ptr = (int *) 0x108; // 264 in bin
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

You get this

> ==755107==  ***Address 0x108 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd***

Your process have no access to the memory address. The reason why 264 is printed is because this is the decimal conversation of 0x108

```
printf( "%d", 0x108);
```

You provided `%d` to printf, `printf` tries to cast the value as integer. Pass `%p` to get back the address

Answer (score 0):

With `int * ptr = (int *) 0x108;` your pointer points to the address `0x108`.
If you want to set the integer, use

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 0x108
```

With `printf("%d\n", ptr);` you just print the content of ptr assuming it is a number. That's why you actually print the address. To print the content, use

```
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

Note that this (using your old declaration and setting of ptr) should segfault as you access memory which is unlikely to be assigned to your current process.

Comment: yeah but when i print the content of the pointer it crashes, every time, but its just a way of hard coding a memory address as  i understood

Comment: Yes, it crashes as you do not own the memory at 0x108. To make it work you would need to use an address you own which could be done by using malloc for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, yes, you can use this for things such as memory mapped I/O.

For example, let's say you have a memory-mapped random generator device in an embedded system that will intercept memory accesses to location `0xf100` and place aa random value on the data bus. You can use code such as:

```
int getRandom(void) {
    static int *randIo = (int*)0xf100;
    return *randIo;
}
```

The important bit the is the indirection `*randIo`. The gets a *value* from the memory location (not the the memory location itself, which would be `randIo` without the indirection).

That would be `*ptr` in your case, rather than `ptr`. But what that will do on an arbitrary (memory-protected) system will be anyone's guess :-)

Answer (score 0):

> when i do methemetic operation like ++ its adds 4 to the value
> (probably because the sizeof(int) is 4) but can someone explaine to me
> here whats going on?

ptr is pointer to int. When you add integer to pointer you perform pointer arithmetic. ++ operator will advance pointer to the next int in memory. If size of int on your machine is 4 bytes then address will be incremented on 4 bytes. Pointer arithmetic is close to operations with array. arr[x] = arr + x. That is if you want to get fifth element of array you can use indexing (arr[4]) or you can use pointer arithmetic (like arr + 4).

> Note that this (using your old declaration and setting of ptr) should segfault as you access memory which is unlikely to be assigned to your current process.

Because indexing of arrays in C is not checked (this is responsibility of programmer) you easily can access memory address that is not allocated to your process and this will cause OS error.
And with address 0x108 you likely will always obtain error because in some operating systems low addresses are not allocated to user. Often 64K. This is done to catch errors with pointers.